# Checkbox remains same size when zooming in or out

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox and when I all the way out it still remains the same size as it did when I was at normal 100% zoom.  I want it to scale proportional to the zoom so when I zoom out it gets smaller and doesn't cover up everything else.

Comment: It's a known Chrome bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84973